# Run script only once for 5 minutes (Linux)

Tags: php, linux, cron

I have a php script that I'd like to run for a specific amount of time (e.g. 5 minutes), but only once. With cron jobs this will run indefinitely. Is there another way?

Comment: Can you please explain what this is for? There may be a better alternative

Comment: A user specifies the amount of time he wants the server to collect data. To do so I have created a seperate php script that I call with cron jobs. But now I realised the script will indeed run for the specified time, but it will also run every day!!!

Comment: Look into the `at` and `batch` commands. More here: http://kb.iu.edu/data/aewo.html.

Comment: I already checked this but there seems to be no way to include the running time.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this is:

1. When something triggers to need for the cron job to run, put a flag somewhere that the cron job will read.
2. Have cron job that runs all the time asking "do I need to run?". It checks hte flag. If it sees it, it deletes the flag and runs for specified time. If not, just wait until it next runs (to check for the flag)
3. In the actual cron job, set "max_execution_time" to 5 minutes. Then it shouod stop at (or just over) 5 minutes. To be more precise, include a timer in your script running in a loop, if you can.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I came up with an alternative. I call the exit() function when the time is correct. I also use the exec() function and run it as a background job. What to you think?

Comment: Fair enough - it is works, great. The exit() was what I was referring to by the timer in a loop, but if exec does the job, great.